# App Center - Unfortunately this feature couldn't be enabled

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am using Microsoft.AppCenter 1.5.0 nuget packages in my Xamarin.Forms app.  After launching my app on Android, and during the authentication to Azure Active Directory, a temporary webpage launches that is only supposed to occur once.

Unfortunately, it launches every single time you launch the mobile app.  It works though, I mean it logs you in, but it's annoying plus my users wonder what is wrong because there is this web page they have to close with the following error:

[image]

Comment: without any code to look at it's difficult to say what the problem is.  Did you try contacting the App Center team as it suggests?

Answer (score 2):

I found out by trial and error what the problem was.  In HockeyApp console it's called the AppID.  In App Center it's called the App Secret (even though it's not the secret).  This secret (or AppID) in App Center has dashes were it doesn't have dashes in HockeyApp.  Since I've upgrade my app from using HockeyApp to using App Center, I was copying the AppId from a previous config.  Well, this won't work becuase it doesn't have the dashes.

So, in short.  Within AppCenter go to your Android app, then hit "Setting" and you should see the ID you need to copy and paste in your AppCenter.Start() command.